# Yaml addressing and template with GAE is not working ? TemplateDoesNotExist just by simple change in yaml ?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, django-templates, yaml

I have problem with using template in Google App Engine by Python.
the thing is, when I address my static folder in Yaml, I can NOT access to my template and when I remove it, it is access able. look at the files.

```
this is my file structure
-src\
----\calc.py
----\main.py
----\index.html
----templ\
---------\calc.html
---------\js
---------\css

YAML:
handlers:
- url: /.*   script: main.py

MAIN.PY
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
      ('/', MainPage),
      ('/calc',Calc)
      ], debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

Calc.py
class Calc(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            temp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templ/calc.html')
            outstr = template.render(temp, temp_val)
            self.response.out.write(outstr)
```

**THE RESULT IS : 
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
I can reach my file and the template addressing is working**

BUTTTTTTT

when I add the following line to my YAML to access to my css and js and so on. IT is not access able

```
YAML:

    handlers:
    - url: /.*
      script: main.py

    - url: /templ
      static_dir: templ

or If i change order of them :
YAML:

    handlers:
    - url: /templ
      static_dir: templ

    - url: /.*
      script: main.py
```

BOTH are NOT working and there is my error

**Status: 500 Internal Server Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/Users/em/Documents/workspace/NerkhARZ/src/calc.py", line 26, in get
    outstr = template.render(temp, temp_val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 88, in render
    t = load(template_path, debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 185, in load
    return _load_user_django(path, debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 110, in _load_user_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/loader.py", line 79, in get_template
    source, origin = find_template_source(template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/template/loader.py", line 72, in find_template_source
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist, name
TemplateDoesNotExist: calc.html
```

Please help me through this, there must be simple solution for it. I really dont believe that GAE is that much fool....

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files designated as static in `app.yaml` are not available to application code in the python runtime. They are only served directly the the user's browser in response to requests matching the regular expression in `app.yaml`.

Do not mark templates as static. Only files that should be served as-is to the user, such as javascript, CSS, and images, should be marked as static.

Comment: OK , I got your point, BTW, is there any option to exclude this particular file form whole directory or not ?

Comment: No. Store templates and stuff to be served statically in different directories.

Comment: I have change my strcture to this :  '---/app/*.py   ---/templates/*.html' how can I define it in the Yaml ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: Your templates don't get mentioned in app.yaml at all; only scripts and files served statically directly to the user's browser do.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problem identified by Wooble, you're adding your `static_dir` handler after your `.*` script handler. Handlers are processed in order, so the `static_dir` handler will never be executed, since all requests are caught by the `.*` one.